# How to get error codes for Dns.GetHostAddresses

Tags: c#, dns

Still new with C#.
I'm trying to get the error codes for my line below so that I know if the hostname is a validhost or not. I did some research on sockets but I am not sure how to use it.

IPAddress[] IPstr = Dns.GetHostAddresses("hostname");

Answer (score 0):

It throws different kind of `Exception` for exceptions *(pun intended)*:

| Exception | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `ArgumentNullException` | `hostNameOrAddress` is `null`. |
| `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` | The length of `hostNameOrAddress` is greater than 255 characters. |
| **`SocketException`** | **An error is encountered when resolving `hostNameOrAddress`.** |
| `ArgumentNullException` | `hostNameOrAddress` is an invalid IP address. |

You probably want to listen for the `SocketException` like:

```cs
public static bool IsHostReachable(string hostname)
{
    try
    {
        _ = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);
        return true;
    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The host could not be reached!")
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Source: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses)*